# Analytic formula for integral $\int_{-\pi}^\pi (\cos\theta)^n(t\cos\theta + \sqrt{1-t^2}\sin\theta)^n\mathrm{d}\theta $ in terms of special functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, special-functions, spherical-coordinates

For $t \in [-1,1]$ and a nonnegative integer $n$, define
$$
I_n(t) := \int_{-\pi}^\pi (\cos\theta)^n(t\cos\theta + \sqrt{1-t^2}\sin\theta)^n\mathrm{d}\theta = \int_{-\pi}^\pi (\cos\theta\sin(\theta + \alpha))^n \mathrm{d}\theta,
$$
where $\alpha := \arcsin(t)$.

> **Question.** What is an analytic formula for $I_n(t)$, perhaps in terms of special functions ?

I'd also be interested in a recursion formula for $I_n$.

**Observations.** $I_0=2\pi$, $I_1(t) = \pi t$, $I_2(t) = \dfrac{\pi}{4}(2t^2 + 1)$, $I_3(t) = \dfrac{\pi t}{8}(2t^2 + 3)$.

---

### Update

This question has been fully answered by user Azlif below. Here is a follow up question [Simplify via special functions, a certain sum involving binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4242436/168758)

Comment: You are looking for a differential equation, but have you at least attempted to differentiate (one or twice) under the integral sign (permitted operation in this framework) ?

Comment: Noting that $d\alpha/dt = -t/\sqrt{1-t^2}=-\tan\alpha$, we have
$$
I_n'(t) = -n\int_{-\pi}^\pi (\sin\theta \cos^{n-1}\theta\sin^n(\theta+\alpha) +\tan\alpha\cos^{n+1}\theta \sin^{n-1}(\theta+\alpha))d\theta,
$$
but I don't know how that helps.

Comment: In general, I'm interested in $I_h(t) := \int_{-\pi}^\pi h(\cos\theta)h(\sin(\theta + \alpha))d\theta$, where $\alpha =\alpha(t) := \arcsin(t)$, and $h:[-1,1] \to \mathbb R$ is a sufficiently smooth function.

Comment: I think you should differentiate with respect to parameter $\alpha$, which is simpler.

Comment: @JeanMarie. Could you elaborate ? By the way, are you OK ? Cheers :-)

Comment: @Claude Leibovici I have attempted to extract a second degree ODE but it looks apparently more difficult than I thought at first... Everything OK on my side. And you ? Cheers.

Comment: We can take $z = e^{i \theta}$ and find $[z^{2 n}] ((z^2 + 1) (z^2 - e^{-2 i \alpha}))^n$, which gives the Legendre polynomials:
$$I_n = 2^{1 - n} \pi (-i \cos \alpha)^n P_n(i \tan \alpha).$$

Comment: @Maxim Very interesting. You can give this answer in the continued question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4242436) by the same author that has forgotten to give the forward link.

Comment: @Maxim Thanks for the very insightful observation. Using well-known differential equations satisfied by the $P_n$'s should also give a differential equation for the $I_n$'s. BTW, which convention are you using for the Legendre polynomials, the one with $P_2(x) = (3x^2-1)/2$, for example ?

Comment: @Maxim Using your formular, $\alpha=0 \implies I_n = 2^{1-n}\pi (-i)^n P_n(0)$, which is imaginary for odd $n$. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Ignore previous comment, as $P_n(0) = 0$ for all odd $n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the trigonometric identity for multiplication on your last integral we have $$\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta + \alpha) = \frac{1}{2}(\sin (2\theta + \alpha) + \sin \alpha).$$

Thus, the integral can be written as $$\frac{1}{2^n} \int_{-\pi}^\pi (\sin (\alpha + 2\theta) + t)^nd\theta.$$
We can then expand this integral using binomial expansion as follow
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sum_{k = 0}^n {n \choose k} \sin^{k}(\alpha + 2\theta) t^{n - k}d\theta &= \sum_{k = 0}^n t^{n -k}{n\choose k}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin^k(\alpha + 2\theta) d\theta\\
&= \sum_{k = 0}^n t^{n -k} {n\choose k} \int_{-\pi}^\pi(t \sin 2\theta + \sqrt{1 - t^2} \cos 2\theta)^k d\theta
\end{align*}

To continue further, we need the following facts:

1. $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin^{2m} 2\theta \cos^{2n} 2\theta \, d\theta = \frac{\pi}{2^{2m +2n - 1}}S(m,n) $$
2. If either $m$ or $n$ is odd, then $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin^m 2\theta \cos^n 2\theta \, d\theta = 0.$$

Where $$S(m,n) = \frac{(2m)!(2n)!}{m!n!(m+n)!}$$

We can evaluate the last integral as follow. If $k$ is odd then the integral equals zero, so we only need to find the value when $k$ is even.

For even $k$, we have

\begin{align*}
&\int_{-\pi}^\pi(t \sin 2\theta + \sqrt{1 - t^2} \cos 2\theta)^k d\theta\\
&= \sum_{j = 0}^{k/2} {k\choose 2j}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} t^{2j} (1 - t^2)^{k/2 - j} \sin^{2j} 2\theta \cos^{k - 2j}2\theta \, d\theta\\
&= \sum_{j = 0}^{k/2} {k\choose 2j} S(j,k/2 - j) t^{2j} (1 - t^2)^{k/2 - j} \frac{\pi}{2^{k - 1}}\\
\end{align*}
Then,
$$I_n(t)= \pi\sum_{k = 0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}   \sum_{j = 0}^{k } {n\choose 2k}{2k\choose 2j} S(j, k - j) t^{n - 2k}t^{2j}(1 - t^2)^{k - j}. \frac{1}{2^{n + 2k -1}}$$

Comment: Nice way to solve it ! $\to +1$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I wonder  if the formula simplify if $t=0$ or $t=1$. In fact, I'm ultimately interested in $I_n(0)$, $I_n(1)$, and $I_n'(0)$. I suspect the nested sums would collapse into to well-known special functions, or else simplify thanks to some wise combinatorial identity. thanks again!

Comment: Could you give a hint why the given integral is equal to your first formula $\frac{1}{2^n} \int_{-\pi}^\pi (\sin (\alpha + 2\theta) + t)^nd\theta.$ ?

Comment: @Jean Marie I used the trygonometric identity for the multiplication of cosine and sine.

Comment: Thanks. I see: $\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta+\alpha)=\frac12 (\sin(2\theta+\alpha)+\underbrace{\sin(\alpha)}_t)$. Maybe you could include this explanation ?

Comment: @Jean Marie Sure! Thank you, I will add it. By the way, I'm not even sure about my last answer:). There might be some minor/major mistakes there. The idea seems to work though.

Answer (score 1):

*Too long for comments.*

As usual, there are two patterns depending on the parity of $n$.

For even  values of $n$,

$$\color{blue}{I_{2n}=\frac \pi {a_n} P_{2n}(t)}$$ the $a_n$ corresponding to sequence $A224446$ in $OEIS$.

The very first polynomials are

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2n & P_{2n}(t) \\
 0 & 2 \\
 2 & 2 t^2+1 \\
 4 & 8 t^4+24 t^2+3 \\
 6 & 16 t^6+120 t^4+90 t^2+5 \\
 8 & 128 t^8+1792 t^6+3360 t^4+1120 t^2+35 \\
10 & 256 t^{10}+5760 t^8+20160 t^6+16800 t^4+3150 t^2+63 \\
12 & 1024 t^{12}+33792 t^{10}+190080 t^8+295680 t^6+138600 t^4+16632 t^2+231
\end{array}
\right)$$
For  odd  values of $n$,
$$\color{blue}{I_{2n+1}=\frac \pi {b_n} t\,Q_{2n}(t)}$$ the $b_n$ corresponding to sequence $A061549$ in $OEIS$.

The very first polynomials are

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2n+1 & Q_{2n}(t) \\
 1 & 1 \\
 3 & 2 t^2+3 \\
 5 & 8 t^4+40 t^2+15 \\
 7 & 16 t^6+168 t^4+210 t^2+35 \\
 9 & 128 t^8+2304 t^6+6048 t^4+3360 t^2+315 \\
11 & 256 t^{10}+7040 t^8+31680 t^6+36960 t^4+11550 t^2+693 \\
13 & 1024 t^{12}+39936 t^{10}+274560 t^8+549120 t^6+360360 t^4+72072 t^2+3003
\end{array}
\right)$$

In both series of polynomials, there are clear patterns which are worth to explore using $OEIS$.

In fact, a CAS produces an ugly antiderivative which involves several  hypergeometric functions. I have obtained some expressions but they are so long that they will not fit in the page.

*To be contiuned (I hope and wish)*

Comment: Interesting approach. Thanks ! $\to$ + 1.

Comment: @dohmatob. The accepted answer is superb.

Comment: There is a one-line comment by user Maxim, namely that $I_n(\alpha) = 2^{1-n}(-i\cos\alpha)^n P_n(i\tan\alpha)$, where $P_n$ is the $n$th Legendre polynomial. Since the Legendre polynomials are well-understood functions, with lots of functional and combinatorial identities involving them, this is in a sense the "book solution" to the problem.