# Simplify via special functions, a certain sum involving binomial coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, special-functions

For $t \in [-1,1]$, $\alpha = \arcsin(t)$, and integer $n \ge 0$, define $I_n(t)$ by
$$
\begin{split}
I_n(t) &= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos^n\theta\sin^n(\theta + \alpha)d\theta = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi (\sin(2\theta+\alpha)+t)^nd\theta\\
&= \sum_{k = 0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}   \sum_{j = 0}^{k } {n\choose 2k}{2k\choose 2j} S(2j, 2k - 2j) t^{n - 2k}t^{2j}(1 - t^2)^{k - j}. \frac{1}{2^{n + 2k -1}},
\end{split}
$$
where $S(m,n) := \dfrac{(2m)!(2n)!}{m!n!(m+n)!}$ and the last equality in the above series of identities is thanks to this ME post https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4242413/168758.

> **Question.** What is are analytic formula for $I_n(0)$, $I_n(1)$, and $I_n'(0)$, perhaps in terms of special functions ?

### Observations

- If $n=0$, then $I_n(t) \equiv 2\pi$, and so $I_n(0) = I_n(1) = 2$ and $I_n'(0) = 0$.
- If $n=1$, then $I_n(t) \equiv t$, and so $I_n(0) = 0$, and $I_n(1) = I_n'(0) = 1$
- If $n=2$, then $I_2(t) \equiv (2t^2 + 1)/4$, and so $I_n(0) = 1/4$, $I_n(1) = 3/4$ and $I_n'(0) = 0$,
- If $n=3$, then $I_n(t) \equiv t(2t^2 + 3)/8$, and so $I_n(0) = 0$, $I_n(1) = 5/8$, and $I_n'(0) = 3/8$.
- ...

Comment: I think this is easier if you go back to the original formulation, $$I_n(t) :=\frac1\pi \int_{-\pi}^\pi (\cos\theta)^n(t\cos\theta + \sqrt{1-t^2}\sin\theta)^n\mathrm{d}\theta$$  For the first two, substituting $t=0$ and $t=1$ give standard problems that can be solved by one integration by parts.  For the third one you have to differentiate under the integral sign.  I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: Indeed, thanks to a comment under the original question, one has $I_n(t) = 2^{1-n}(-i\cos\alpha)^n P_n(i\tan\alpha)=2^{1-n}(-i\sqrt{1-t^2})^nP_n(i t / \sqrt{1-t^2})$, where $P_n$ is the $n$th Legendre polynomial. Thus, we have $I_n(0) = 2^{1-n}(-1)^n P_n(0)$, for example.

Comment: This seems problematical when $t=1$.  I get $I_n(1)=\frac{2n-1}{2n}I_{n-1}(1)$, so that $$I_n(1)=\frac{2\cdot(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}$$

Answer (score 1):

There is a one-line comment by user Maxim, under the original question here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4242413/168758, namely that
$$
\begin{split}
I_n(t) = 2^{1-n}(-i\cos\alpha)^n P_n(i\tan\alpha)=2^{1-n}(-i)^n(1-t^2)^{n/2}P_n(it(1-t^2)^{-1/2}),
\end{split}
$$
where $P_n$ is the $n$th Legendre polynomial and $i := \sqrt{-1}$. It follows directly that $I_n$ is $\mathcal C^\infty$ on $(-1,1)$ with derivative
$$
\begin{split}
I_n'(t) = &n2^{1-n}(-i)^{n+1}t(1-t^2)^{n/2-1}P_n(it(1-t^2)^{-1/2})\\
&\quad + 2^{1-n}(-i)^n(1-t^2)^{n/2}(i(1-t^2)^{-1/2}+it^2(1-t^2)^{-3/2})P_n'(it(1-t^2)^{-1/2}),
\end{split}
$$
for all $t \in (-1,1)$.
In particular, one computes
$$
\begin{split}
I_n(0) &= 2^{1-n}(-i)^n P_n(0),\\
I_n(1) &= 2^{1-n}P_n(0)\delta_{n=0},\\
I_n'(0) &= 2^{1-n}(-i)^{n+1} P_n'(0).
\end{split}
$$

As sanity check, noting that $P_2(x) = (3x^2-1)/2$, we have that for $n=2$,
$$
\begin{split}
I_2(t) &= 2^{1-2}(-i)^2(1-t^2) P_2(-it(1-t^2)^{-1/2})\\
&=-2^{-1}(1-t^2)(3(-it(1-t^2)^{-1/2})^2-1)/2\\
&= 2^{-1}(3t^2 + 1-t^2)/2 = (2t^2+1)/4,
\end{split}
$$
which corresponds to the formula stated in the question.